# how to stop and start liberty cluster and its members

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have around 8 WLP servers running I did setup collective and its members. However, when I go to the WLP frontend and selected the cluster perform stop nothing happens. If I want to stop all WLP Servers I need to go each host and stop each server by running server stop server1, 2, 3 etc...

I want to run a command from one server and stop all of the Servers (1,2,3,4,5,etc..)

**Attaching my Controller server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<server description="CollectiveController">  
   <featureManager>
      <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
      <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
      <feature>collectiveController-1.0</feature>
   </featureManager>
   <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" host="*" />
   <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
   <include location="${server.config.dir}/uiController_include.xml" />
   <hostAuthInfo rpcPort="22" rpcHost="host-01" sshPublicKeyPath="{server.config.dir}/resources/security/ssh/id_rsa" useCollectiveSSHKey="true" />
</server>
```

**uiController_include.xml**
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<server description="This file was generated by the 'collective create' command on 2022-09-26 13:03:00 EDT.">`
`<featureManager>`
  `<feature>collectiveController-1.0</feature>`
`</featureManager>`
`<variable name="defaultHostName" value="host-01" />`
`<quickStartSecurity userName="wasadmin" userPassword="wasadmin123" />`
`<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="true" />`
`<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/key.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/trust.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="serverIdentity" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/serverIdentity.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="collectiveTrust" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/collectiveTrust.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="collectiveRootKeys" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/rootKeys.p12" />`
````

**CollectiveMember server.xml**
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<server description="ui-07">`
  `<featureManager>`
`<feature>javaMail-1.6</feature>`
`<feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>`
`<feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>`
`<feature>mdb-3.2</feature>`
`<feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>`
`<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>`
`<feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>`
`<feature>websocket-1.1</feature>`
`<feature>cdi-2.0</feature>`
`<feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>`
`<feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>`
`</featureManager>`
`<include location="${server.config.dir}/ui-server-07_include1.xml" />`
`<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9081" httpsPort="9446" />`
`</server>`

CollectiveMember include ui-server-07_include1.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<server description="This file was generated by the 'collective join' command on 2022-09-27 16:25:05 EDT.">`
`<featureManager>`
  `<feature>collectiveMember-1.0</feature>`
`<feature>clusterMember-1.0</feature>`
`</featureManager>`
`<clusterMember name="uiCluster" />`
`<remoteFileAccess>`
`<writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>`
`</remoteFileAccess>`
`<variable name="defaultHostName" value="host-02" />`
`<hostAuthInfo useHostCredentials="true" />`
`<collectiveMember controllerHost="host-01" controllerPort="9443" />`
`<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="true" />`
`<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/key.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/trust.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="serverIdentity" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/serverIdentity.p12" />`
`<keyStore id="collectiveTrust" password="{xor}KjY8Ky0zLyg7" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/collectiveTrust.p12" />`
`</server>`

Comment: Please post the configuration of your collective controller and one of the member.  Also, check the logs of both and post any errors.

Comment: @Rowe attached the XMl's. please check. thanks a lot.

Comment: Are there any error messages or FFDCs in the controller or member logs when you execute stop?

Comment: I dont see any error in controller or member logs. On ffdc I see below 

Exception = com.ibm.ws.collective.rest.internal.cache.InconsistentCacheException
Source = com.ibm.ws.collective.rest.internal.cache.MemoryAPI
probeid = 306
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.collective.rest.internal.cache.InconsistentCacheException: The allServersStopped tally for host-01,runtimes collection has gone negative

Comment: when you said "selected the cluster perform stop nothing happens." exactly how are you performing that?  Are you using the Admin Center?  Running a console command?

Comment: also, have you reviewed https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=collectives-configuring-liberty-collective, specifically, look at the member log files to see if they're joining the collective properly:
CWWKX8112I: The server's host information was successfully published to the collective repository.
CWWKX8114I: The server's paths were successfully published to the collective repository.
CWWKX8116I: The server STARTED state was successfully published to the collective repository.

Comment: yes I login to admincenter and select the cluster then nothing happens. However, when I stop and start by selecting single server from the admincenter it works.

Comment: are you seeing the above mentioned messages in the member logs?